# Tensorflow: How to index one element per sample in batch

Tags: tensorflow, indexing

I have the following setup:

```
B = Batchsize
N = Number of Objects
T = Number of Targets
L = Length of feature embedding per target
```

For each object, I want to attend to a target. The model decides which target to attend to by taking the argmax of a vector `attention_weights` with `shape=[B,N,T]`:

`pick = tf.math.argmax(attention_weights, axis=2)`

So `pick` has the shape `[B,N]` and each entry is an index. Now I would like to use these indices to access the correct target features

```
target_features.set_shape(target_features, [B, D, L])
features_picked = tf.some_function(target_features, pick)
```

My question is, what to use for `tf.some_function`? Is it something related to tf.gather? I have trouble figuring out how to use it in this case.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

PS: I am using tf.**version** = '1.13.1'

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, I will accept the answer once I confirmed it's doing what it should:

I tiled `target_features` so it has shape [B, N, T, L]

Then I do:

```
features_picked = tf.batch_gather(target_features, indices=pick)
```

where `features_picked` has shape `[B, N, 1, L]`